# Is there any reason not to boot from the BIOS on a multi-OS system?

Tags: multi-boot, bootloader

I've been having a hell of a time getting my bootloader to play nicely with the various OS installations I have on my computer. As it stands, Windows is the only culprit (accidentally installed it in legacy mode).

To get into Windows I pull up the boot menu at the splash screen, and boot from there. Obviously this isn't the best way to go about thing, but is there anything *really bad* about this approach?

Comment: Other than being inconvenient, I can't see any other issue doing that.

Comment: @Jonno Yea, it is inconvenient, and I can't see any other issue either. Just being paranoid I suppose.

Comment: What Bootloader are you using?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin I'm using clover. I think I can get it working, I just don't have the time now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than being inconvenient I suppose, and that typically you can't have more than one bootloader on a drive.You pick a boot *drive* not a partition.

So, on a *single disk* dual partition system? It simply would not work. You'd have to use the bootloader on the drive and pick an OS from there.

On a multidisk setup with one OS per drive, it works pretty well - I currently dualboot linux (which picks up windows anyway) and windows (which is blissfully unaware its sharing a chassis with linux) and use the uefi boot menu to pick what to boot off of. It then loads that drive's boot sector and you're good to go.